# Custom Guice Scope, or a better approach?

Tags: design-patterns, scope, guice

Here's my problem:

It's first important to know that I'm writing a simulation.  This is a standalone application, and is single-threaded.  I have essentially two classes of objects that have different scoping requirements.

1. Classes that should be used as singletons throughout the entire simulation.  An instance of Random, as an example.
2. Groups of classes that are created together, and within the group, each instance should be treated like a Singleton.  For example, say `RootObject` is the top level class, and has a dependency to `ClassA` and `ClassB`, both of which have a dependency to `ClassD`.  For any given `RootObject`, both of its dependencies (`ClassA` and `ClassB`) should depend on the same instance of `ClassD`.  However, instances of `ClassD` should not be shared across different instances of `RootObject`.

Hopefully that makes sense.  I can think of two approaches to this.  One is to mark all of the injected objects as Singletons, create the root injector, and spin off a child injector each time I need to create a new `RootObject` instance.  Then, the instances of `RootObject` and all of its dependencies are created as Singletons, but that scoping information is thrown away the next time I go to create another `RootObject`.

The second approach is to implement some type of custom scope.

The Guice documentation gives conflicting advice...  On one hand, it says that you should have a single injector, and that ideally it is called once to create some top level class.  On the other hand, it says to stay away from custom scopes.

Comment: I have an idea that @Assisted injection could be used here, but I'm having trouble seeing exactly how it should be used...

Comment: @Josh: Where does the docu say to stay away from scopes?

Comment: @A.H., http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes - first line.  "It is generally recommended that users do not write their own custom scopes — the built-in scopes should be sufficient for most applications."  I have found that the first approach works very well - creating child injectors as needed.  We just need to be careful that the "singletons per group" don't accidentally get bound in the parent injector, but that's fairly easy to check.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for the quote. Besides of this quote I would have recommended a custom scope, as this would be a perfect fit in your case given _one_ constraint: Each class belongs exactly into one of your "groups".

Comment: Yeah, I realize that a custom scope is probably the preferred way...  Guidelines like the one quoted are just that...  guidelines.  I couldn't really find sufficient examples of custom scopes to be comfortable creating one.  If you had any implementation ideas, I'd be interested in seeing them.

Answer (score 14):

It seems to me like you need a scope for each instance of `RootObject` and all its dependencies.

In Guice you can create a custom scope, say `@ObjectScoped`, like this:

```java
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ScopeAnnotation
public @interface ObjectScoped {}
```

Now just place `RootObject`, `A`, `B` and `D` into this scope:

```java
@ObjectScoped
public class RootObject {

    private A a;
    private B b;

    @Inject
    public RootObject(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

}

@ObjectScoped
public class A {

    private D d;

    @Inject
    public A(D d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public D getD() {
        return d;
    }
}

// The same for B and D
```

Now each `RootObject` has its own scope. You can implement this as a simple `HashMap`:

```java
public class ObjectScope {

    private Map<Key<?>,Object> store = new HashMap<Key<?>,Object>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
        return (T)store.get(key);
    }

    public <T> void set(Key<T> key, T instance) {
        store.put(key, instance);
    }

}
```

To integrate these scopes with Guice you will need a `com.google.inject.Scope`-implementation which lets you switch the scopes and the corresponding wiring in your `Module`.

```java
public class GuiceObjectScope implements Scope {

    // Make this a ThreadLocal for multithreading.
    private ObjectScope current = null;

    @Override
    public <T> Provider<T> scope(final Key<T> key, final Provider<T> unscoped) {
        return new Provider<T>() {

            @Override
            public T get() {

                // Lookup instance
                T instance = current.get(key);
                if (instance==null) {

                    // Create instance
                    instance = unscoped.get();
                    current.set(key, instance);
                }
                return instance;

            }
        };
    }

    public void enter(ObjectScope scope) {
        current = scope;
    }

    public void leave() {
        current = null;
    }

}

public class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule {

    private GuiceObjectScope objectScope = new GuiceObjectScope();

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindScope(ObjectScoped.class, objectScope);
        // your bindings
    }

    public GuiceObjectScope getObjectScope() {
        return objectScope;
    }

}
```

Initialize your program like this:

```java
ExampleModule module = new ExampleModule();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
GuiceObjectScope objectScope = module.getObjectScope();
```

Create the first instance of `RootObject` and its corresponding scope:

```java
ObjectScope obj1 = new ObjectScope();
objectScope.enter(obj1);
RootObject rootObject1 = injector.getInstance(RootObject.class);
objectScope.leave();
```

Just switch the scope for a second group of objects:

```java
ObjectScope obj2 = new ObjectScope();
objectScope.enter(obj2);
RootObject rootObject2 = injector.getInstance(RootObject.class);
objectScope.leave();
```

Test if your requirements are met:

```java
assert rootObject1 != rootObject2;
assert rootObject1.getA() != rootObject2.getA();
assert rootObject1.getA().getD() == rootObject1.getB().getD();
assert rootObject1.getA().getD() != rootObject2.getB().getD();
```

To work with a group of objects just enter its scope and use the injector:

```java
objectScope.enter(obj1);
B b1 = injector.getInstance(B.class);
objectScope.leave();
assert rootObject1.getB() == b1;
```

Comment: I don't know if leaving a scope just after the instance creation is enough. Something like lazy instantiation of a Provider<T> dependency may fail...

Answer (score 5):

With a little setup, Guice can provide two-tier scoping without a custom scope.  The outer one is `@Singleton`, and the inner is `@RequestScoped`, provided by the `servlet` extension.  This works even if you're talking about something other than a Java EE servlet container.

Have a single, root-level injector to handle your singletons.  Be sure to declare the request scope annotation in your root-level module as so:

```java
public class RootModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // Tell guice about the request scope, so that we can use @RequestScoped
    bindScope(RequestScoped.class, ServletScopes.REQUEST);
  }
}
```

When you want to enter a sub-scope, you do this:

```java
private void scopeAndInject(final Object perRequestSeed) {
  try {
    ServletScopes.scopeRequest(new Callable<Void>() {
      public Void call() {
        Injector requestScoped = getRootInjector().createChildInjector(
          new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
              bind(Object.class).toInstance(perRequestSeed);
            }
          }
        );

        requestScoped.get(Something.class);

        return null;
      }
    }, new HashMap<Key<?>, Object>()).call();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

What we're doing here is using `ServletScopes.scopeRequest` to run the anonymous `Callable` inside a new request scope.  The `Callable` then creates a child injector and adds a new binding for any per-request seed objects.

The seeds are objects that `@RequestScoped` things would need but couldn't be created by Guice alone, like requests or iteration IDs.  The new `HashMap` passed as the second argument to `scopeRequest` is another way to literally insert seeds into the new scope.  I prefer the submodule way, since the [bindings for the seeded values are always required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8977492/580412) anyway.

The child injector is then "in" the request scope and can be used to provide `@RequestScoped` things.

See this also: [How to use ServletScopes.scopeRequest() and ServletScopes.continueRequest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8402012/580412)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a provider?  It would be easy to write one that meets your requirements, e.g.:

```
import com.google.inject.Provider

class RootObjectProvider implements Provider<RootObject> {

    ...

    @Override
    RootObject get() {
        ClassD d = new ClassD( .... );
        ClassB b = new ClassB( ..., d, ...);
        ClassC c = new ClassC( ..., d, ...); // Note that b and c share d.
        return new RootObject(b, c, ...);
    }
}
```

You can use the provider two ways:

1. Bind it as a provider with either the `@Provides` interface or the `.toProvider()` binding decoration.
2. Inject the provider directly and invoke it to create `RootObject` instances as needed.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Hmm... creating instances with `new` is the original sin in a DI framework. Especially if _any_ of those classes want some more stuff injected.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why do you need to have singletons ?

I would not recommend to create custom scope. The best and easiest way to mix scopes is to inject providers instead of objects. With the providers you can control the scope of your object from you business code logic.

See this [Guice documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders#Providers_for_Mixing_Scopes) for details.

Comment: I don't think this applies.  If I were mixing request-scoped objects with singletons, then sure...  this would work great.  But, I need to mix singletons with a scope that doesn't already exist.  It seems like the easiest way for us to do this is going to be to use child injectors.

Comment: To address your Singleton question - we have two levels of stateful objects - ones whose instances need to be shared across the entire simulation (like a random number generator), and others whose instances need to be shared within a small sub-component of the simulation.  Different sub-components dynamically get created, and each sub-component needs its own instance of this per-component singleton; however, other objects within that sub-component need to access the same instance.